# react-native-paytm not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, paytm

I am trying to use react-native-paytm for payment gateway, I followed the steps what was there in react-native-paytm module, but it is not working for me, Even i don't Know the error and Don't Know how to resolve it
Here is the code that what i have done

```
payNow(){
   // alert("payNow")
    var details = {
      generationUrl: "https://cinealerts.com/webservices/paytm/xxx.php",
      validationUrl: "https://cinealerts.com/webservices/paytm/xxx.php",
      mid: "my mid", // Prod
      industryType: "Retail", //Prod
      website: "APP_STAGING", //prod
      channel: "WAP",
      amount: "5",
      orderId: "12345678",
      requestType: "DEFAULT",
      email: "hussian@gmail.com",
      phone: "7777777777",
      theme: "merchant",
      custId: "9988344556",
    };
    paytm.startPayment(details);
  }
```

when i click on button it will call the paynow function, in payNow function one popUp is open and automatically it closed with out showing anything, I don't know how to resolve this issue, and even i don't know that what is the issue.
Any one please give me suggestions that how to resolve this issue, Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A better documented fork:
https://github.com/sujayjaju/react-native-paytm

It worked for me on Android. I still need to test on iOS

Comment: But the documentation says tested on iOS not on android. Can I use it for react native android?

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal - Yes, I have used it successfully on Android

Comment: Can you share a gist or code? I am stuck with processing screen of paytm

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct values of paytm parameters.

In your code, you are using **APP_STAGING** in website parameter. It should be **APPSTAGING**.

To check the correct parameters value of website parameter, follow the steps :-

- Log into your Paytm dashborad  - https://staging-dashboard.paytm.com
- Go to settings->profile
- Check value of Website

Also I need to add one more parameter to get it working i.e. mode:'stage'.
I am sharing my code that worked fine for me in android.

```
var details = {
                        mid: "my_mid",
                        industryType: "Retail", //Prod
                        website: "APPSTAGING", //prod
                        channel: "WAP",
                        amount: 100,
                        orderId: "ORDER_12390",
                        email: "abc@gmail.com",
                        phone: 7777777777,
                        custId: "CUST-12879",
                        checksumhash: "checksum generated using paytm sdk",
                        callback: "my_call_back_url",
                        mode:'stage',
                    };
                    // alert(JSON.stringify(details));
                    paytm.startPayment(details);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51264762/react-native-paytm-not-working-for-android