# react-native-paytm not working for android

Tags: payment-gateway, react-native, paytm

I am trying to use [react-native-paytm](https://github.com/elanic-tech/react-native-paytm), I followed the steps and example that was there in it. But after clicking on pay via PayTm button, it is showing me raw html having a form with all my data in hidden input element.

Can someone assist me with it?

Comment: This issue has been fixed automatically, when I tried to rebuild the project again

Comment: can you please provide snippt for integrate paytm payment

Comment: @rimmy can you share your code snippet that you are using for paytm. You can hide the parameters that are not to be shared.